# Apache re-directing issue

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have a site in localhost that uses a shortened URL's from

`http://localhost/Portal/mysite/profile.php?id=1`

to

`http://localhost/Portal/mysite/profile/1/this_is_id`

Using the below `.htaccess` below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/.*$  /Portal/mysite/profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

But, I need the URL to be instead as `http://localhost/Portal/mysite/this_is_id`

This is all in localhost, that is why `.com` does not appear, but the site file is `mysite` 
So, I  tried sending a link that is in my `mysite/index.php` to `mysite/profile.php` with `$id` but it is not working. Anyway simple suggestion would be fine, thanks

**UPDATE**

---

Ok, I did as both you asked, but this is the function that is sending a user from index page to profile page, and I do not know how to modify it, even though I have done what both of you asked.

```
    // sql query goes here. 
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $url = "/profile/$row[id]/".preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]/', '-', $row['company']);  

        echo "<h4><a href=\"$url\" class=\"urln\">". substr($row['company'], 0,26)."</a></h4>
                    ";

    }
```

the echo is the link, now when I press on that link, It takes me to page not found

**UPDATE 2**

---

[image]
this is the image of my directory, the link is in index.php and when clicked it sends me to profile.php all the above file is situated in `WAMP/www/Portal/mysite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#for subdirectory
RewriteBase /Portal/mysite/
#for localhost
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
#RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

`.htaccess` and `profile.php` in `Portal/Site` directory.

UPDATE:

```
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $url = "/profile/".preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]/', '-', $row['company']) . "-" . $row[id];
    echo "<h4><a href=\"$url\" class=\"urln\">". substr($row['company'], 0,26)."</a></h4>";

}
```

`profile.php`

```
var_dump($_GET);

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $params = explode('-', $_GET['id']);
    $id = (int)array_pop($params);

    var_dump($id);
}
```

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Portal/mysite/
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

run your link ( f.e.: `localhost/Portal/mysite/profile/This-is-name-12` ) and result:

```
array (size=1) 'id' => string 'This-is-name-12' (length=15)

int 12
```

`12` is your profile id.

Comment: I tried your approache it is not working, please check my updated answer @mkjasinski

Comment: @mkjansinski when I clicked on the link it sends me to `http://localhost/profile/1/This-is-title` but the page says 404 not found. example of link is just a simple href as it is shown in my updated question, please help me on this one, I am lost

Comment: @kranzdot check now my answer, if you run from localhost, you must change `Rewritebase` to `/`.

Comment: I checked, and it sends me to a 404 page with this address `http://localhost/profile/2/this-is-title` I do not want that `/2/` to appear, I just want it to be like `profile/this-is-title`

Comment: Hi, I have included a picture in the question, pls check it out

Comment: @kranzdot `WAMP/www/Portal/mysite` is root directory for `localhost`? links must be build without `/[id]/`, only `localhost/profile/This-is-name`?

Comment: `localhost/Portal/mysite/` is the the address when I am accessing the site live,  whereas `WAMP/www/Portal/mysite` is the path of the file accessed from `C:\`

Comment: Also, I removed the `/$row[id]/` from the URL in the function and not it is page not found.

Comment: @kranzdot ok, `WAMP/www` is root for localhost, in `.htaccess` must be add `RewriteBase /Portal/mysite/`.

Comment: I changed it, still 404 page, the problem is with the function above, because it is not sending the id from the index page to profile.php

Comment: @kranzdot you must send `id`, check my example.

Comment: I did `http://localhost/Portal/mysite/profile/This-is-name-12` and it gave me error, but I did `http://localhost/Portal/mysite/profile.php?id=This-is-name-12` and it gave me `array (size=1)
  'id' => string 'This-is-name-12' (length=15)
int 12` I did all as you asked, I am sorry about this, I have been trying to solve it for 2 days

Comment: @kranzdot you have problem with `mod_rewrite`, show me logs from apache, when do you run `http://localhost/Portal/mysite/profile/This-is-name-12`, `404` or `500`? show me your `.htaccess`.

Comment: Hey sorry, this one works `http://localhost/Portal/mysite/profile/This-is-name-12` I just had forgot to replace `mysite` with the actual name of my site, so it is giving me now `array (size=1)
  'id' => string 'This-is-name-12' (length=15)
int 12` but, when I clicked the link from index.php as per the function you gave me  I get `404 Not Found` error and this is in the url this `http://localhost/profile/Company-test-LLC`

Comment: @kranzdot in your configuration file set const: `define('SUBDIRECTORY', '/Portal/mysite');` and add this to your `foreach` loop: `$url = SUBDIRECTORY . "/profile/".preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]/', '-', $row['company']) . "-" . $row[id];`, links will be correctly. If you run under the domain without subdirectory, set `SUBDIRECTORY` const to `''` and `RewriteBase /` in your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$  profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

if the Rule (`.htaccess`) is in your `/Portal/mysite/` directory, and `profile.php` is there as well.

Comment: I tried your approache it is not working, please check my updated answer @Jon